# How to get last hour, last month and yesterday in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to get the last hour, last month and yesterday from current date and time, I am using Date() Object to get current date and time:

```
function fetchCurrentDateTime() {
    var currentDateobj = new Date()
    var Day = currentDateobj.getDate()
    var Hour = currentDateobj.getHours()
    var Month = 1+(currentDateobj.getMonth())
    var Year = currentDateobj.getFullYear()
    console.log('Today is:', Day+'-'+Month+'-'+Year);
    console.log('yesterday was:', Day-1+'-'+Month+'-'+Year);
    console.log('Its', Hour, 'hrs');
    console.log('It was', Hour-1, 'an Hour back.');
    console.log('This is:', Month, 'Month');
    console.log('It was', Month-1, 'Month, a month ago.');
    console.log('It is', Year);
    }
```

I want a function which would return me not only date or time but complete datetime like:

```
Today: '2013-05-21 10:06:22'
Yesterday: '2013-05-20 10:06:22'
Current Hour: '2013-05-21 10:06:22'
Last Hour: '2013-05-21 09:06:22'
Current Month: '2013-05-21 10:06:22'
Last Month: '2013-04-21 10:06:22'
```

I also want to ask what if hour is `00:00:00`, what would be the result of last hour then? Same is with month and date.

Comment: You mean like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/dGvc3/

Comment: I mean to say that I don't want to make strings like `year+'-'+month+'-'+day`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```js
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*60*60*24));
var hourago = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000*60*60));
    
console.log("Today:", today);
console.log("Yesterday:",yesterday);
console.log("Hours Ago:", hourago);
```

`getTime()` returns the timestamp of your *Date* object. You can then just substract the proper number of milliseconds and make a new object from that number. If needed, you can now format the dates in a way that you wish.

Comment: @ Squeezy: Can you please help me to format the result like: `'2013-05-21 10:06:22'`, whereas the time stamp looks like:`Date {Wed May 22 2013 11:02:03 GMT+0500 (PKT)}`

Comment: Take a look at http://www.datejs.com/ This will probably solve your problems in one go.